# Sum of 2 raised to the power of every element in a line of Pascal’s triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I know that the elements of a line in Pascal’s triangle add up to $2^n$ . What about:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{\binom{n}{k}}$$ For example, line $n = 2$ adds up to $8$. $n = 3$ adds up to $20$. Is there any formula?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've added MathJax to make your post clearer. You might have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future posts.

Comment: Thanks. I am typing in a phone and didn’t know how to do that

Comment: First few terms are $2,4,8,20,80,2116,\ldots$ OEIS knows not of such a sequence

Comment: @gt6989b: Looks like user1000 needs to submit a new sequence to the OEIS! I find it remarkable that it's not there.

Comment: Fourth term should be $100$ not $80$. Sequence A001315 in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A001315

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new triangle out of pascal triangle by replacing $\binom {n}{k} $ with $2^{    \binom {n}{k}  }$ then   and the additive property

$$\binom {n+1}{k}= \binom {n}{k}  +  \binom {n}{k-1} $$ translates to  the multiplicative  property $$ 2^{  \binom {n+1}{k}} =  2^{\binom {n}{k}}\times 2^{\binom {n}{k-1}}$$

The product of elements on the $n_{th} $ row would be $ 2^{2^n} $

I did not find a simple formula for the sum of rows of the new triangle.